# What is the most efficient way of converting a variable in a dataframe to a matrix in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, data-manipulation

I need to perform the following operation on a dataframe in R 3.4.1 on Windows

1. Split the dataframe by a categorical variable -> get a list of dataframe splitted by that categorical variable (getting the list is not necessary, that's just how I do it).
2. Extract a variable from the splitted dataframe list.
3. Combine the splitted variables in a matrix.
4. Transpose the matrix.

Currently I'm doing these operations as follows:

```
t(sapply(split(df, df$date), function(x) x$avg_mean))
```

I'd like this operation to be more efficient, that is:

1. Use the least memory possible, i.e. not duplicate objects, if possible. I may need to use this with a 1.5 GB dataframe.
2. Be fast with large dataframes.

What is the most appropriate/efficient way of doing this in R? Parallelization is also appreciated but not strictly necessary since I'm not sure I'll be able to use it.

If you need a toy dataframe, use [this](https://pastebin.com/p4b0eTuP).

Comment: why not directly use split on the variable of interest? (`split(df$avg_mean, df$date)`)

Comment: Ok, that would be already an improvement I didn't think of.

Answer (score 1):

The best approach is probably to go in the direction suggested in comments with `split(df$avg_mean, df$date)` and bind the results together. A pretty close second would be to just convert your vector to a matrix directly exploiting the fact that the number of observations for each date must be constant in your case. Some approaches and their speed below:

```r
library(microbenchmark)
library(data.table)

dat <- data.frame(date = rep(c('A', 'B', 'C'), each = 1000), 
                  avg_mean = rnorm(3000))

f1 <- function(dat) {
  t(sapply(split(dat, dat$date), function(x) x$avg_mean))
}

f2 <- function(dat) {
  matrix(dat$avg_mean, nrow=length(unique(dat$date)), byrow = T)
}

f3 <- function(dat) {
  do.call(rbind, split(dat$avg_mean, dat$date))
}

f4 <- function(DF) {
  DF = data.table(DF)
  DF[ , index := 1:.N, by=date]
  DF_trx = dcast(DF, index~date, value.var = "avg_mean")
  DF_trx$index=NULL
  t(as.matrix(DF_trx))
}

microbenchmark(f1(dat), f2(dat), f3(dat), f4(dat))
#> Unit: microseconds
#>     expr      min       lq      mean    median        uq       max neval
#>  f1(dat)  456.064  475.542  617.0032  489.9390  515.6205  4250.471   100
#>  f2(dat)  107.062  110.907  150.3135  117.6060  124.1925  2992.862   100
#>  f3(dat)   74.313   79.927  122.2712   84.4455   89.4250  2504.850   100
#>  f4(dat) 3797.694 3893.886 4563.4614 4021.6505 5053.5800 15757.085   100
```

It seems `do.call(rbind, split(dat$avg_mean, dat$date)` is probably your best bet.

Answer (score 0):

I have added an index for each group and data table cast functions to achieve the same. You should use data table to make it more efficient

```
DF = data.table(DF)
DF[ , index := 1:.N, by=Col1]
DF_trx = dcast(DF, index~Col1, value.var = "Col2")
DF_trx$index=NULL
as.matrix(DF_trx)
```